# IndexError: tuple index out of range for svm

Tags: python, svm

```
1. ratios = [(100,2), (100, 20), (100, 40), (100, 80)]
2. for j,i in enumerate(ratios):
3.     print(j,i)
4.     print(i[0])
5.     print(i[1])
6.     clf = SVC(C =0.001, gamma = 'auto')
7.     X = ratios[j][i[0]]
8.     Y = ratios[j][i[1]]
9.     clf.fit(X,Y)
10.    print(ratios[0][0])
```

As i am trying to access the first of first (100) and first of second (2) element from ratios in line number 7 and 8 i am still getting the error "tuple out of index". Logically it seems to be correct as i have printed it in line n0 4,5 and 10. So i am not getting what is missing?

Comment: Check line `4` and `5` of your code. You already know the solution. This is how you can access values of tuple. The error you are getting because, your are using `100` and `2` as indices of tuple.

Answer (score 0):

the `for i,j in ratios` loop means that for every element in axis '1', (stored as `j`), and for every element in the array inside each `j` (stored as `i`).

For the first loop, this means `j` is `Whatever is in element 0 of the root array` , and `i` is `Whatever is in j`.

J = `[(100,2)]`

I = `[100,2]`

Therefore, using `ratios[j][i[0]]` is Like saying

`Get the element at ratios Where the values are (100,2) and then get index 100`

What you wan to use is

`X=ratios[j][0] / Y=ratios[j][1]` , as this is

`Get the element at ratios Where the values are (100,2) and then get index 0 and then index 1`